# How to separate the icon of the app from the icon of the first activity?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an issue in the manifest file. I have an icon for my application and for my first activity. but when I run the app on my device the app icon is the icon of my first activity. this my manifest file

[image]

I had the same issue with the label of the app and the first activity. I resolved it by setting the title of the activity at the run time with the `function setTitle()`. is there a way to do the same with icons?

Comment: Are you trying to add icon in the title bar of your activity? I would appreciate if you add screenshot of the output as well. I mean screenshot of problem from your phone or emulator

Comment: Please explain it properly with what you have tried.

Comment: @MuntasirAonik can you add image in title bar ?? I think he is trying to do that

Comment: @Dharmaraj check the answer bro .

Comment: Cool :) I think thats what he needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210973/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-muntasir-aonik).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/back_menu_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material"
        android:gravity="left"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

2. You can set logo programmatically:

   ```
   Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   if (getSupportActionBar()!=null){
       getSupportActionBar().setTitle("bla bla bla");
       getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
   }
   ```

Comment: I dont have a toolbar

Comment: What do you want to get?

Comment: Thats what I am looking for

Comment: You must need a toolbar to do so. Add a toolbar and setbackground="@null" . Then follow my answer.